# gremlin fold() unfold() throwing errors: "Vertex with id 70 was removed" and "The incoming object is not removable"

Tags: gremlin, tinkerpop, gremlin-server

This query works:

```
choose(V().hasLabel("user"), V().hasLabel("user").drop())
```

But is searching 2 times for the vertex "user", I want to optimize it to 1 time, so I changed it for this one:

```
choose(V().hasLabel("user").fold(), unfold().drop())
```

If I do that trick multiple times in my query it throws:

```
Error: ResponseError: Server error: Vertex with id 70 was removed. (500)
```

I don't understand what that means, maybe fold() does not overwrite previous fold() calls, I don't know.

Is there an alternative to fold() unfold() for this use case? I've tried:

```
choose(V().hasLabel("user").as("u"), select("u").drop())
```

but that does not work, it seems `.as()` don't save anything when is called inside `choose()`

I also tried:

```
choose(V().hasLabel("user").store("u"), select("u").drop())
```

But throws another error I don't understand: `The incoming object is not removable`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your first attempt with:

```
choose(V().hasLabel("user"), V().hasLabel("user").drop())
```

is not as expensive as you think. The `if` portion of `choose()` (i.e. the first child traversal) does not iterate all users. It immediately returns `true` if one "user" is found". Your `then` child traversal will iterate all "user" vertices. Also, you don't provide a `false` value to `choose()` so in that case, I believe that you will end up calling the `drop()` traversal for either situation:

```
gremlin> g.inject(1).choose(V().hasLabel('no-exist'),constant(1))
==>1
gremlin> g.inject(1).choose(V().hasLabel('no-exist'),constant(1),constant(2))
==>2
```

Of course, I'd wonder why you need to do an `if/then` here at all because calling `V().hasLabel("user").drop()` without `choose()` will remove all "user" vertices found, or if none are found, just do nothing.

For this traversal:

```
choose(V().hasLabel("user").fold(), unfold().drop())
```

note that `V().hasLabel("user").fold()` will always return "true" because you `fold()` which is a reducing step which will return a `List` of items in the stream. If the stream is empty you get an empty `List` and thus `choose()` will use the `true` path there. In any event, your `unfold()` is not unrolling what is returned from the first `choose()` parameter - it unfolds the same `Traverser` object handed to the `choose()` step. You don't have what comes before the `choose()` so I can't say what that is.

I'm not completely sure but based on your remaining traversal examples, I think you might be misusing `choose()` in general. You don't seem to have need for an `if/then` or `switch` style operation. With Gremlin you don't need to check if something is present in order to remove it and it is in fact cheaper not to do so as mentioned earlier.

Comment: Sorry my examples do not represent what I need, that is why it looks like I don't need the choose. I've tried the following and it worked, what do you think?:
    ``choose(V().hasLabel("user").store("x"), select("x").unfold().drop(), addV("whateverV"))``

Comment: Using `store()` in that context does not quite work as you would think. It will only store the first user in "x" because as I mentioned in my answer the `if` portion of `choose()` only checks for existence of a value in the stream (i.e. the first). I suppose you could switch to `aggregate('x')` which isn't lazy but I'd prefer to avoid use of a side-effect list all together.  It I don't know what comes before the `choose()`, but I think I would prefer, `sideEffect(V().hasLabel("user").drop()).addV("whatever")`.